# Using rsync to test changes before git commit

Tags: git, rsync

I'm working using a combination of rsync and git to work on a repo but wondering if this process makes sense. Here's my current setup:

1. project is set up as a Git repo on Machine A (my local laptop) and Machine B (deployment server)
2. make local edits in repo on Machine A (my local laptop)
3. rsync to Machine B and test
4. commit and push changes from Machine A
5. Here is where I get into trouble. If I go to the repo on Machine B, it says I have unstaged changes. Should I do a `git pull` here? Or first do a `git reset --hard` then `git pull`? Or something else?

I know this can be avoided if I just push the changes to the repo from Machine A and then pull them from Machine B, but I want to avoid making a bunch of unnecessary commits before I have the chance to test my changes.

Comment: just a `git reset --hard` then `git pull` will do the trick

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable. Is there a more streamlined way to do pre-commit testing? Is CI an option?

Comment: you could use CI, but that would require a commit to trigger the CI process. if you're running tests on the deployment server i would suggest moving that into a CI environment. If you're worried about commits cluttering up the git history, thats a non issue since you could work on a feature branch and squash commits :)